# How to sum values of third level nested array of objects across all documents in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, aggregate

I have a mongoose document having the following Schema:

**Products**

```json
{
   "section":"",
   "category":"Food & Drink",
   "sub_category":"Main Dish",
   "product_code":"ST",
   "title":"Steak",
   "description":"Served with sauted vegetables",
   "tags":[
      
   ],
   "warranty":"None",
   "product_variants":[
      {
         "variant_code":"ST1",
         "variant_title":"Rib Eye",
         "images":[
            
         ],
         "status":"Active",
         "variant_details":[
            {
               "size":"6oz",
               "local_price":800,
               "local_discount":"0",
               "foreign_price":0,
               "foreign_discount":"0",
               "inventory":[
                  {
                     "branch_id":{
                        
                     },
                     "quantity":94
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "size":"10oz",
               "local_price":1000,
               "local_discount":"0",
               "foreign_price":0,
               "foreign_discount":"0",
               "inventory":[
                  {
                     "branch_id":{
                        
                     },
                     "quantity":147
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "size":"12oz",
               "local_price":1200,
               "local_discount":"0",
               "foreign_price":0,
               "foreign_discount":"0",
               "inventory":[
                  {
                     "branch_id":{
                        
                     },
                     "quantity":199
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The above document shows only one object in the `product_variants` field but please note that there could be several objects as well. I need to sum the quantity for each size and product variant.

How would I do that using aggregate function? I am using mongoose in node js environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query
(its based on the last comment in the previous answer, similar query but multiplies that quantity with the local price)

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/13uw4K563FP)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$product_variants"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$product_variants.variant_details"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$product_variants.variant_details.inventory"
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "total_local_price": {
        "$multiply": [
          "$product_variants.variant_details.inventory.quantity",
          "$product_variants.variant_details.local_price"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,    // or "$_id" if you want only for 1 document
      total_qty: {
        $sum: "$total_local_price"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this aggregation query:

- Fisrt `$project` to get only the `quantity` values. It generates the following output:

```
"array": [
      [
        [
          94
        ],
        [
          147
        ],
        [
          199
        ]
      ]
```

- So next step is to use `$unwind` three times to flat the array.
- And `$group` by `_id` using `$sum`

```
yourModel.aggregate([{
  "$project": {
    "array": "$product_variants.variant_details.inventory.quantity"
  }
},
{
  "$unwind": "$array"
},
{
  "$unwind": "$array"
},
{
  "$unwind": "$array"
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "size": {
      "$sum": "$array"
    }
  }
}])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Wd1Z37AoMdr)

**Edit**
As [Takis _](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4882692/takis) suggested into the comments if you want to get all values from your entire collection (not only for each document) you can `$group` using `null` as [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0siQsjoL4JD)

Comment: `"_id": "$_id"`  => group and sum quantity/ document 
`"_id": null`     =>  group and sum quantity/collection (in case the wants this)

Comment: Good point! I'm going to add into the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @Takis_ and J.F. ! I'll try your suggestion and get back here with an update

Comment: Thanks guys, this is just what I wanted!

Comment: @Takis_, is there anyway how I could multiply the local_price field with the inventory.quantity and sum up the value across all documents? Basically, I need to know the total worth of products.

Since it's related, I don't want to create a new thread. 

Thanks

Comment: @AhnafAhmed i added one more answer that does that i think